MongoError: Authentication failed. when I try to create a task definition in AWS
i try to create a task definition with two containers in AWS. The json of the task definition is the following
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-north-1:637423633568:task-definition/goals-task-definition:1",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "goals-backend",
            "image": "xflamant/goals-node",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "goals-backend-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "command": [
                "node",
                "app.js"
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "MONGODB_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "secret"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MONGODB_USERNAME",
                    "value": "max"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MONGODB_URL",
                    "value": "localhost"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/goals-task-definition",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-north-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "mongodb",
            "image": "mongo",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "mongodb-27017-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 27017,
                    "hostPort": 27017,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME",
                    "value": "max"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "secret"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "goals-task-definition",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::637423633568:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::637423633568:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 1,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "3072",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2024-06-28T14:55:33.825Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::637423633568:root",
    "tags": []
}

I don't see what is wrong in my task definition, there is a username/password defined for mongodb and the message error seems to be the fact that the username/password credential is wrong. Could it be another reason ?
And when I try to deploy it, I have a mongodb authentication error. The print screen of the message error is the following. Can you help me ?

